# How do I save a Javascript app onto the microSD card after I image Raspberry Pi OS onto it?

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi-os

I am new to this and exploring a lot of concepts. Please lmk if I have any misconceptions.

I imaged Rasberry Pi OS on my microSD card (32 GB) using the Raspberry Pi Imager via raspberrypi.com. The capacity of the microSD card becomes 267.4 MB, so I believe that partitions are created. I cannot see the other partitions using Disk Utility on Mac.

I would like to save a Javascript app I created onto the microSD card before connecting it to my Raspberry Pi Zero. Is this possible? Or do I need to boot my Raspberry Pi and download the file separately?

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Please delete this.

Answer (score 1):

You may add your JavaScript to the "rootfs" which after installing the OS with the imager application is mounted at `/media/user/rootfs`. This is on Linux and if it is not on Mac by default, then mount the `rootfs` partition and copy whatever files you require.

Note that there is another `boot` partition where you may do boot config manipulation by editing the file `config.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

The `/boot` partition is formatted as FAT, which macOS can read and write. The root and other partitions are formatted as ext3, or similar, which macOS cannot readily access.

You could try to squeeze your app into the `boot` partition, which will appear on your Mac at `/Volumes/boot` and likewise in the Finder.

You may need to compress it (as the boot partition is small) using `gzip` which is included in macOS. It will look like:

```
gzip < YOURAPP > /Volumes/boot/YOURAPP.gz
```

You can then boot your RasPi and unzip your app to your HOME directory with:

```
gunzip < /boot/YOURAPP.gz > $HOME/YOURAPP
```